# Should an answer be deleted because most readers won't like it?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answer

My answer to [Why do Christians use ancient Greek polytheistic connotations when defining the literal meaning of Hell?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/92482/why-do-christians-use-ancient-greek-polytheistic-connotations-when-defining-the/92488?noredirect=1#comment260847_92488)
was recently deleted because:
"*This is just a rant against Christians you disagree with and has almost nothing to do with the question that was asked.*".

It's certainly something "*most people on this site won't agree with*", as that's literally what I said in my first sentence,
and I did expect downvotes from those that disagree with my point (as opposed to with how well it answered the question).
But I didn't expect it to be deleted.

It isn't a rant, and it *does* answer the OP's question (and I suspect in the way that was wanted).

The question was: "*Why do Christians use ancient Greek polytheistic connotations when defining the literal meaning of Hell?*",
and my answer gave a history of Christianity that explains exactly why this happened.

A quick summary is that most of what today calls itself Christianity is not the same religion practiced by the Apostles; it is a counterfeit Christianity descended from the pagan Greek/Roman religion.

People that believe in Roman Catholicism will obviously not like what I said, but that doesn't necessarily mean it is wrong or should be deleted.

Comment: You state (in your deleted answer) _During this current era, God is not trying to save the world, God is not trying to convert everyone, and most certainly God is not battling with Satan over "immortal souls" and trying to save them from perpetual torture._ But you do not state what God is trying to do. You do not offer us the _positive alternative_ to your _negative_ assessment.

Comment: @NigelJ without having read the answer, RB (and a couple of others) has put forth that which you deem missing many times - based on the inspired biblical text. Maybe you missed it.

Answer (score 3):

**Should an answer be deleted because most readers won't like it?**

The short answer is **no**. But your answer does not really address the question being asked. That is why it was deleted.

Your answer to the question [(***Why do Christians use ancient Greek polytheistic connotations when defining the literal meaning of Hell?***)](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/92482/why-do-christians-use-ancient-greek-polytheistic-connotations-when-defining-the/92488?noredirect=1#comment260847_92488) is only somewhat addressed in the second to last paragraph, and is unsourced at that.

As Curiousdanni stated in his comment to your post: **The second last paragraph is the *only* the only part that's even close to relevant, and it has no supporting evidence for its claims.**

About 90% of your answer does not directly address the question at hand, even remotely.

This is not the only post on Christianity SE that someone has thought might read like a rant. Answers must stick to the parameters of the question posted in order to avoid being off the subject matter of a question.

Comment: But that second last paragraph wouldn't make sense without the preceding 90%. In particular, most readers' perspectives are based on the common Catholic/Protestant view of things, so they lack the background that I had to supply in order for them to understand the answer.

Comment: @Ray Butterworth I think you can make a better post on this by limiting your response to the usage of the *“ancient Greek polytheistic connotations when **defining** the literal meaning of Hell”* The essential is there!

Comment: Then my answer would be more or less the same as anyone else's.  The various definitions of Hell etc. are a symptom of the underlying situation. It's that underlying situation that I wanted to present.  Specifically "Christianity" today is directly descended from Roman/Greek paganism, not from Apostolic Christianity.

Comment: @RayButterworth That is not the point of this question. Answer the question, leave the rest out. Descendant from pagan origins is not invoked in the post, so it is irrelevant here. A true understanding of Greek would be beneficial in forming a reasonable answer. Your post does run like a rant against Catholicism. The New Testament writers used many Greek mythological terms that were understood by the the people of their day.

Comment: Hades and Sheol both mean the grave; that's not really in dispute.  The question was about why modern Christianity interprets it as something completely different.

Comment: @RayButterworth If you want to go that route, what does modern [exegesis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exegesis) have to say in this matter. Can you quote modern exegesis material? That will keep your post academically sound and not a personal opinion.

Comment: Strong's H7585 says "sheol" means "grave, hell, pit", and G86 says "hades" means "the grave, death, hell".
They both mean the same thing, and as the OP notes, neither matches the modern concept.
The question is *why* doesn't the modern concept match what exegesis shows.
A correct answer would have nothing to do with exegesis, other than that exegesis shows that the modern concept is wrong.

Comment: @RayButterworth Five different Greek gods are mentioned by name In the New Testament alone! There are several allusions to the names of other gods. Ancient Greek culture had it’s influence on the Sacred Authors. The Greek verb ταρταρῶ,  which occurs once in the New Testament (in 2 Peter 2:4), is almost always translated by a phrase such as "thrown down to hell". A few translations render it as "Tartarus"; of this term, the Holman Christian Standard Bible states: "Tartarus is a Greek name for a subterranean place of divine punishment lower than Hades." (2  Peter 2:4) Greek connotations!

Answer (score -1):

Knowing RB's penchant for sticking to the biblical text (mostly), this will always cause some degree of friction with traditional views. We have a DV system that is abused to begin with - especially these days as many seem to regard it as a punitive means of castigating views not like their own. Whether there is a biblical basis is often irrelevant. The Q in topic had 2 DV just because! Why? It was well researched and laid out and deserves the space it occupies.

Any Q (or A) that queries long-held traditional views should not be ridiculed. If there is merit to a tradition then it has nothing to fear by a reasonable and thoughtful response. If a belief is based on unbiblical sources as suspected here, then it warrants further inspection.

**Should an answer be Mod-deleted** because *they* think it is bad, wrong or against tradition? No. If it is deemed offensive, perhaps. But 'offensive' (or a rant) is often confused with 'not traditional'.

In this case many will never know! RB is a valued and constructive member and contributor and should be allowed the system to function as intended. Accepting DV's just *because* is accepted by those not *following the masses* but are willing to contribute anyway.

A *perceived* 'rant' is often mistaken for the preliminary groundwork required to give a *non-traditional* answer the foundation it requires to make any sense or to show logical progression.

> People that believe in Roman Catholicism will obviously not like what I said, but that doesn't necessarily mean it is wrong or should be deleted. (RB)

This is the nub of it - as expressed over and over in many forms here for a long time. This *is* a predominately Roman Catholicism website that is supposed to be a Christian one judging by the title up the top. If you say the right thing you will be rewarded, if you don't...

Comment: I am not too sure about your statement that this website is predominantly Roman Catholic. It is not true for moderators. Until 2017 there were none. Do not think this site was bias then or now. Most questions are about Catholicism, but that does not mean the poster is/was Catholic at all. Also Ray Butterworth did not use one biblical referenced source in his answer, yet you insist he has a “penchant for sticking to the biblical text”.

Comment: @Ken, one only needs to observe the reputation gathered by those expressing such a view compared to those who do not.